# Issue with rolling random "dice" numbers and then summing values (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying for hours now to figure out why my random "dice" roll function won't produce the results I'm looking for.

My roll function:

```
function roll(min, max, count) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
    var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){

    result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1);
  }
 return result;
}
```

My call function:

```
var stats = [];
var STR = roll(1,6,STRrolls);
Logger.log(STR);
```

STRrolls has a value of 3. The log looks like this:

> [19-03-20 23:26:12:730 GMT] [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]

Here is where I trip up. I'm trying to sum the 3 values and then store it in the "stats" array as a single value, so that I can repeat the process with a few other arrays too.

Here is a better sample of my script:

```
function roll(min, max, count) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
    var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){

    result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1);
  }
 return result;
}

function sumArr(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b
  }, 0);
}

function CHAR {
  var C_R = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Char_Ref')
  var STRrolls = C_R.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var DEXrolls = C_R.getRange("F3").getValue();
  var RESrolls = C_R.getRange("F4").getValue();
  var EMProlls = C_R.getRange("F5").getValue();
  var STArolls = C_R.getRange("F6").getValue();

  var stats = [];

var STR = roll(1,6,STRrolls);
Logger.log(STR);

var DEX = roll(1,6,DEXrolls);
var RES = roll(1,6,RESrolls);
var EMP = roll(1,6,EMProlls);
var STA = roll(1,6,STArolls);


      stats.push([STR,DEX, RES, EMP, STA])

      rangeStats.setValues(stats);
      rangeClass.setValue(CLASSval);
      rangeLevel.setValue(1);

}
```

The issue is that running this function gives the same log before and after:

> [19-03-20 17:03:13:560 PDT] [3.0, 1.0, 4.0] [19-03-20 17:03:13:561
>   PDT] [3.0, 1.0, 4.0]

Comment: Where's the code you've tried that fails to sum the values? Have you tried `Array#reduce`? Where are the error messages associated with your code? Surely you found other pages on the internet that deal with summing the contents of an array... So what happened when you tried those recommendations?

Comment: Hi, @tehhowch - Yes, I have tried reduce but couldn't get it to work. It just returns the same log result. I was using this:
function sumArr(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b
  }, 0);
}  You sound upset (could be wrong, I am autistic). I aplogise if I haven't given enough detail. I tried. I do not have all of the different methods I have tried, and their associated errors, as I replaced them each time they did not work. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why I am being downvoted. I have tried searching for the answer and tried doing it for myself and have reached the limit of my knowledge and so am asking for help - why are people annoyed at that? :-/

Comment: Without you showing what you've done, people will just repeat your work, wasting everyone's time. Show your code, in your question, that reflects how you summed and how you looked at the sum. Note that array class methods generally do not modify the source array...

Comment: Thank you, @tehhowch - I have edited my question to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Where is the 2nd log statement? I also don't see any use of your `sumArr` function - you are directly inserting the original array into your `stats` variable.

Answer (score 2):

like that?:

```
function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}
var stats = [];
var STR = roll(1,6,STRrolls);

stats = STR.reduce(getSum);
Logger.log(STR);
```

you pushed each value in the array and didnt do any add operation.

Comment: Gives the same log before and after calling the getSum function:                             
[19-03-20 23:50:56:079 GMT] [3.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[19-03-20 23:50:56:080 GMT] [3.0, 5.0, 6.0]

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be an interesting problem.  Establishing the max and the min of each roll is not as obvious as one might guess at first.

```
function repeatRolls(cnt) {
  var cnt= cnt || 100;
  var mindie=100000;
  var maxdie=-100000;
  var s='<style>th,td{border: 1px solid black;padding:5px;}</style><table>';
  for(var i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
    var rObj=rollTheDice(12,-12,20);
    if(i==0) {
      s+='<tr><th>Roll</th>';
      for(var k=0;k<rObj.roll.length;k++) {
        s+=Utilities.formatString('<th>Die %s</th>',k+1);
      }
      s+='<th>Sum</th></tr>';
    }
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td>',i+1);
    for(var j=0;j<rObj.roll.length;j++) {
      s+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', rObj.roll[j]);
      if(rObj.roll[j]>maxdie){maxdie=rObj.roll[j];}
      if(rObj.roll[j]<mindie){mindie=rObj.roll[j];}
    }
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td></tr>',rObj.total);
  }
  s+=Utilities.formatString('</table><br />maxdie: %s<br />mindie: %s',maxdie,mindie);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Rolling the Dice');
}
```

The roll function with max die, min die and number of dice parameters that really work.

```
function getSum(total,num) {
  return total + num;
}

function rollTheDice(max,min,num) {
  var num = num || 6;
  var min = min || 1;
  var max = max || 6
  var roll=[];
  for (var i=0;i<num;i++){
    roll.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1))+min);
  }
  return {roll:roll,total:roll.reduce(getSum)};                         
}
```